# Trying to write a regex where a newline may appear anywhere in a group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex divide text into two parts and ignore everything that comes after these two parts.

The (insufficient) regex I'm trying to use is:

```
/Artikelnummer(?:(&&&))(.*)(?:\s*.*)\W?(?:Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite&&&)((.*)&&&(.*)&&&(\d)+)*/
```

The text I'm matching is saved at these links:

https://regex101.com/r/VDnUoe/1

https://regex101.com/r/j62Mw0/2

**Part 1)** Everything after Artikelnummer and before Dokumentation... (easy to match)

**Part 2)** Everything after `(?:Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite&&&)` that follows the pattern:

```
                                text&&&text&&&digits
```

In one of the above links, the above pattern works except for a new line that is thrown in, which causes some text to be left out that should be included.

The first part is matched:

```
all&&&Vorwort&&&1&&&all&&&Sicherheit&&&2&&&all&&&Richtlinien und Normen&&&3&&&all&&&Produktbeschreibung&&&4&&&all&&&Installation&&&5&&&all&&&Wichtige Informationene zur Inbetriebnahme&&&6&&&all&&&Projektierung - Wichtige Infos&&&7&&&all&&&Anhang 1&&&8&&&all&&&Anhang 2&&&9&&&all&&&Anhang 3&&&10&&&all&&&Anhang 4&&&11&&&all&&&Anhang 5&&&12&&&all&&&Anhang 6&&&13&&&all&&&Anhang 7&&&14&&&all&&&Anhang 8&&&15&&&all&&&Anhang 9&&&16&&&all&&&Anhang 10&&&17&&&all&&&Anhang 11&&&18&&&all&&&Anhang 12&&&19&&&all&&&Anhang 13&&&20&&&all&&&Anhang 14&&&21&&&all&&&Anhang 15&&&22&&&all&&&Anhang 16&&&23&&&all&&&Anhang 17&&&24&&&all&&&Anhang 18&&&25&&&all&&&Anhang 19&&&26&&&all&&&Anhang 20&&&27&&&all&&&Anhang 21&&&28&&&all&&&Anhang 22&&&29&&&all&&&Anhang 23&&&30&&&all&&&Anhang 24&&&31&&&all&&&Anhang 25&&&32&&&all&&&Anhang 26&&&33
```

And then this isn't matched, because a newline is inserted:

```
all&&&Anhang 27&&&34&&&all&&&Anhang 28&&&35&&&all&&&Anhang 29&&&36&&&all&&&Anhang 30&&&37&&&all&&&Anhang 31&&&38&&&all&&&Anhang 32&&&39&&&all&&&Anhang 33&&&40&&&all&&&Anhang 34&&&41&&&all&&&Anhang 35&&&42&&&all&&&Anhang 36&&&43&&&all&&&Anhang 37&&&44&&&all&&&Anhang 38&&&45
```

My question is, how can this regex be rewritten so that a newline could theoretically be placed anywhere within the second part of the text and still match everything I want?

Comment: your pattern `text&&&text&&&digits` doesn't represent the as is, what do you really want? because this `...&&&all&&&Anhang 35&&&...` is not fulfilled by the previous pattern

Comment: @Edwin  How is `all&&&Anhang 27&&&34` not represented by that pattern?

Comment: because when you put `digits` alone then I understand the `text` has no digits - and that is not a pattern you should be more specific

Comment: Instead of trying to match this with regexes, I'd rather parse the whole document into a datastructure and then fetch there the data you're looking for. There has to be some pattern and documentation for this format. What format is that? where did you get it from?

Comment: @Edwin  It's not a real regex, so can be interpreted in several ways.  To me, it's logical that digits may belong to text, but arbitrary text doesn't necessarily belong to digits.

Comment: @Edwin  It's not a real regex, so can be interpreted in several ways.  To me, it's logical that digits may belong to text, but arbitrary text doesn't necessarily belong to digits.

Comment: text can have spaces too and can be empty too, or?

Comment: @Edwin  Sure, I can't think of a language that doesn't allow for spaces in text or the empty string

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want, anyway this regex works with `newline`s too:

```
Artikelnummer(?:(&&&))(.*)(?:\s*.*)\W?(?:Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite&&&)((.*)&&&(.*)&&&(\d)+(\n?)*)*
```

- `\n` matches newline
- `?` is the quantifier for zero or one (if newline is found or not)
- `*` I added this one if more newline are encountered

Comment: Will this work if the newline is placed somewhere else?

Comment: It depends on where you want to place it. The regex is pretty clear, if newline is after numbers in your pattern, then it works, otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a regex like this:

```
(Artikelnummer([\n|\r| |\S]*)(?=Dokumentation))(([\n|\r| |\S]*&&&){2}\d+)*
```

Looking for the `\n\r` and all other non space chars.

Second I wouldn't use the `?:` - for maching every find. The positive lookup `?=` should give you the requirements for the first group.